# Creating ECDH using OpenSSL

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, key-exchange, openssl

For academic reasons, I'm playing around with OpennSSL 1.0.2g. 
I tested RSA encryption/decryption.
I created key exchange with DHKE.
But I'm struggling to find a way, to create ECDH, using only OpenSSL. 
Is it possible to create such key exchange only using OpenSSL?

Comment: See https://jameshfisher.com/2017/04/14/openssl-ecc/ for a good example of ECDH key exchange using openssl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ECDH is included in the ciphersuites, so the only answer is: *yes, this should be possible*.

For your further research, it might help to know that Crypto.SE features a lot of Q&As related to “[OpenSSL ECDH](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/search?q=openssl+ecdh)”.

Also see [the related documentation at the OpenSSL wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Elliptic_Curve_Diffie_Hellman) for practical code examples showing how to use ECDH in OpenSSL, how to use the low-level APIs to achieve the same, and infos about how to handle ECDH and Named Curves.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention whether your academic project was C code or a command line tool was enough?  As OpenSSL provides both, the simplest way to start is to use the OpenSSL command line tool.  The OpenSSL wiki is useful:

https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Command_Line_Elliptic_Curve_Operations

In short, use the OpenSSL command line tool to generate:

- The EC Name Curve parameter file
- The EC Key Pair (which uses the EC named curve parameter file as
  input)
- Extract the Public key from the Key Pair. This is the key you need to share with the other side.
- Derive the Shared Secret with the Peer's public key and the Key Pair you generated.  The derived value is likely to be binary, so on a Linux / mac machine can use use the `xxd` tool to print it in hex

Please remember, ECDH is designed as a Key Agreement Protocol over an insecure channel.  So you should not use the Derived Shared Secret as the actual key.  That is where you need to add an Authenticity step.  I used HMAC-SHA-256 on the derived Shared Secret.  That means both sides need a pre-agreed HMAC Key to complete the process otherwise you risk not knowing who you are exchanging messages with.